# How to set click event function in to AngularJS setInterval

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

In my AngularJS project i have fb login and i'm using [angularjs-socil-login](https://github.com/heresy/angularjs-social-login) plugin for that.when successful login i'm store the access token received.

**problem**

fb access tokens are expire after some times.thats why i though to update the token using `AngularJs  setInterval`.then i have edited `angularjs-socil-login pluging` and added `reLogin` function.that function check login status.if user already connected,i'm calling `FB.login` function and update access token.

this is working fine when i set `$scope.sign` function in to button click.but when i set `$scope.sign` function in to `AngularJS setInterval` it's not working.it's not calling `FB.login` function.Chrome console only showing `hiiiiii fb` message

**Controller.js**

```
$scope.sign = function(){
  $rootScope.newToken="";
  socialLoginService.reLogin();
  if($rootScope.newToken){
    console.log("updated ",$rootScope.newToken);
  }
}

setInterval(function(){
$scope.sign();
}, 3000);
```

**added function (reLogin) in to angularjs-socil-login pluging**

```
reLogin:function($q){
            console.log("hiiiiii fb");

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if(response.status === "connected"){

                        FB.login(function(response) {
                            if(response.status === "connected"){

                                    $rootScope.newToken=response.authResponse.accessToken;
                                    console.log("updated ",$rootScope.newToken);

                            }
                        }, {scope: 'email', auth_type: 'rerequest'});

                }else{

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Or you could lengthen the expiry time of Facebook access tokens (search for the ways of doing it on stackoverflow).

Comment: Facebook’s client-side SDKs should be able to manage that automatically, they see to it that you always have a fresh, working token as long as the user is active in your app. _“fb access tokens are expire after some times.thats why i though to update the token”_ - is there any actual need to do that, do you get errors in some situations otherwise ...?

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.sign = function(){
  $rootScope.newToken="";
  socialLoginService.reLogin();
  if($rootScope.newToken){
    console.log("updated ",$rootScope.newToken);
  }
}

$interval(function(){
$scope.sign();
}, 3000);


use $interval instead of setInterval and inject $interval
```